# How to update JavaFX title during runtime?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm pretty new to JavaFX, and I currently have the following code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        stage.setTitle("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

In the `main` function, I try to change the title of the stage. Unfortunately, the variable scope won't let me do this. I'm curious how I can change the title of my JavaFX window during runtime, since `primaryStage` is just a local parameter.

One thing I've tried is making a global `Stage` and setting `primaryStage` equal to it, but that did not work (kinda obviously). After doing a few searches online, I believe I would need to create a whole new scene every time I do that, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Launch returns ***after*** the JavaFX application is shut down (i.e. the last window is closed). If you know the data before calling `launch`, you can pass the info to this method and retrieve it inside the `start` method using `getParameters`. Note though that it's better to put initialisations like this in the `start` or `init` methods of the application...

Comment: "*One thing I've tried is making a global `Stage` and setting `primaryStage` equal to it, but that did not work (kinda obviously).*" Why did it not work and why is it obvious that it wouldn't work?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score -1):

In your main class you can store a reference to the `Scene` like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private static Scene mainScene;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            mainScene = scene;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        Stage mainStage = (Stage) mainScene.getWindow(); 
        mainStage.setTitle("Hello world");
    }
}
```

And access the `Window` object that it holds.
Note that a `Window` is a super class of `Stage` so you need to use casting to access its properties as a `Stage`

Comment: If you had read my full question you would have noticed that I already tried this, and it did not work for me because a duplicate `Stage` object does nothing to the first.

Comment: Sorry, for this, I'm deleting it.

Comment: @Ptray, I'm really sorry for that but I found another way of doing this. The `Window` class is a superclass of Stage and your scene holds a reference to it. I tested it here and worked for me, even in another class

Answer (score -1):

Just set the title inside `start`:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello world!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to change it dynamically, either store it as a field, or use [`Node#getScene()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getScene()) and [`Scene#getWindow()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getWindow()).

Notes:

- Use `@Override` when applicable, it can only help.
- Don't use `try-catch` statements where they are not needed (or use he minimal scope for them).